# Setting worksheet objects

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub nhap_lieu()
Dim form As Worksheet
Dim danh_sach As Worksheet
'Dim form As Object
'Dim danh_sach As Object
Set from = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")
Set danh_sach = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Danh Sach")

''''' Kiem tra danh sach
If form.Range("E4").Value = True Then
    MsgBox "Ban chua nhap ten thi sinh "
    Exit Sub    
End If
End Sub
```

> rutime error '91' object variable or with block variable not set.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `form` as a variable name. It is bad practice, could be confusing, and it could conflict with built-in objects in some cases. I changed that to `ws` (for worksheet).

Also, you are setting `from` instead of `form`. If you had used `Option Explicit` then it would have caught that typo.

Use `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets` as `Sheets` can refer to chart objects as well.

You do not need `= True` either.

Here's what it should look like.

```
Option Explicit

Sub nhap_lieu()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim danh_sach As Worksheet
  
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Form")
  Set danh_sach = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Danh Sach")

  ''''' Kiem tra danh sach
  If ws.Range("E4").Value Then
    MsgBox "Ban chua nhap ten thi sinh "
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

<sub>Not sure what you need `danh_sach` for, as it's not used at all in your code.</sub>